# Visual Studio Code: Theme One Monokai: Change / Custom Highlight Color for C/C++ `const`

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am using the (amazing) [One Monokai](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=azemoh.one-monokai) theme in visual studio code. One thing that bothers me is that variable modifers like `const` and control flow like `for`, `if`, `while`, ... are displayed using the same color. Based on [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/colorization-cpp), I tried a custom coloring by adding to `settigs.json`:

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[One Monokai]": {
            "rules": {
                "<KEYWORD>": {
                    "foreground": "#A2142F"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried multiple `<KEYWORDS>` listed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide), where I expected either `readonly` or `property` to work. I tried a different, unambigious, keyword, e.g. `variable` - that worked as expected, so the general "frame" is working.

Any idea what keyword has to be? Or do I have to make a workaround using a third party package for specific word highlighting?

Comment: why do you use `semanticTokenColorCustomizations`, you want `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`, find the right TextMate Scope and use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the comment pushing me into the right direction and [this tutorial](https://www.alveeakand.com/how-to-modify-themes-in-vscode/), the working code is

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[One Monokai]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "storage.modifier.specifier.const.cpp",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#A2142F"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```